# PyCord/Discord.py getting 403 forbidden error 50001 Missing Access even though I have all Intents & Permissions

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

I have this code for my PyCord bot,

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
from discord_components import *


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot Ready")

@bot.command()
async def lab(ctx):
    ctx.reply("Welcome to the Lab")

responses = ['yes.gif','no.gif','laugh.gif','ugh.gif']
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot == False and message.channel.id == 798909171587874867:
        gif = random.choice(responses)
        await message.reply(file=discord.File(gif))
```

But when I run the program and try to do the slash command, first it doesn't appear and then I get this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_connect
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 352, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/bot.py", line 1045, in on_connect
    await self.sync_commands()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/bot.py", line 555, in sync_commands
    registered_guild_commands[guild_id] = await self.register_commands(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/bot.py", line 420, in register_commands
    desynced = await self.get_desynced_commands(guild_id=guild_id)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/bot.py", line 252, in get_desynced_commands
    registered_commands = await self.http.get_guild_commands(self.user.id, guild_id)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 332, in request
    raise Forbidden(response, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access
```

These are my Discord permissions in the developer portal
[image: Discord Permissions]

Comment: Is that the *whole* traceback?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Yeah

Comment: Did you add the bot to the guild with only the `bot` scope or also with the `application.commands` scope?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding application.commands as @Chuaat said in the Oauth2 and link generator page.